# How to execute store.load method before rendering next combbox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a three dropdown which are dependent.

ex :  Country state and city.

I select country, state will appear and then I select state city will appear. This is create flow which is working fine.

Now In Edit flow I am facing one issue. While rendering I am calling load store method which is getting executed but it is executing for state and country not for country. Is there any way I can delay the country store.load so it will execute country forst and then state and city.

my code is

```
rendercombo: function () {
        let _this = this,
            combo = _this.getView(),
            comboName = combo.name;
        // Edit case flow. 
       // Some code
        
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(combo.getValue())) {
                let extraPramConfig = combo.extraconfig;
                combo.extraconfig.selectedValue = combo.getValue();
                _this.loadDropdownStore(extraPramConfig);
            }
        }
    },
    


loadComboStore : function(config){
    let _this = this;
        combo = _this.getView(),
            store = combo.getStore();
    store.getProxy().setExtraParams(config);
    // Here I want to execute my first combo then second and third
        store.load({
                callback: function (records) {
                    console.log(records);
                }
        });
    }
```

Here I want to execute my first combo then second and third. Any efficient solution for this

Comment: May you provide some fiddle sample for this task?

Comment: I would create 3 combos with a change listener. And then call the load methods of the store within one or more promises, and beforeLoad change the params based on the value of each combo.

Comment: @devbnz do you have any example for this.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I like to lean on async/await, so I'm assuming this is what you're asking for.  If you use Sencha Cmd and have it transpile to ES5 (or you don't care about browser compatibility), then this should work.  Now obviously you should not use this exactly, as it's a quick test case showing how to use async/await... you should wrap them in `try..catch` and make it a bit prettier, but here's the [example Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38f1) and code:

```
// Extending the idea of Ext.Deferred from
// https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.Deferred.html
Ext.define('StoreOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Store',

    loadAsync: function (config) {
        var deferred = new Ext.Deferred();
        config = config || {};
        // Override any callback, as we'll return the results in the await
        config.callback = function (records, operation, success) {
            if (success) {
                deferred.resolve({
                    records: records,
                    operation: operation
                });
            } else {
                deferred.reject("Error loading Companies.");
            }
        }
        this.load(config);
        return deferred;
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            value1: null,
            value2: null,
            value3: null
        },
        stores: {
            store1: {
                fields: ['Name'],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'data1.json'
                }
            },
            store2: {
                fields: ['Name'],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'data2.json'
                }
            },
            store3: {
                fields: ['Name'],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'data3.json'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Combo 1',
        displayField: 'Name',
        queryMode: 'local',
        bind: {
            store: '{store1}',
            value: '{value1}'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Combo 2',
        displayField: 'Name',
        queryMode: 'local',
        bind: {
            store: '{store2}',
            value: '{value2}'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Combo 3',
        displayField: 'Name',
        queryMode: 'local',
        bind: {
            store: '{store3}',
            value: '{value3}'
        }
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: async function(view) {
            var vm = view.getViewModel();
            var stores = [
                vm.getStore('store1'),
                vm.getStore('store2'),
                vm.getStore('store3')
            ];
            view.setLoading(true);
            for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
                var deferred = stores[i].loadAsync();
                console.log(`loading store ${i+1}`);
                var result = await deferred.promise;
                console.log(`done loading store ${i+1}`, result);
            }
            view.setLoading(false);
        }
    }
});
```